# How to find a spell data in acore_world DB

Tags: mysql, azerothcore

When debugging the SpellEffects.cpp in [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) I found `spell_id` for example `2006` for level 1 resurrection priest spell and `10880` for level 3. There is a `spell_ranks` table that relates the two. However I cannot find the additional spell data for either of them. There is a `spell_dbc` table that seems to contain many columns for spell attributes but these spells do not exist there under `ID` column where `ID = 2006` or `ID = 10880`.

Where is the data for those spells? specially damage(heal), mana cost, and casting time?

Answer (score 1):

`spell_dbc` only contains **overrides** of spells, not the full spell list

more details about this table are available at:

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/spell_dbc

Comment: Thank you I was looking for documention